# Export output in excel from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

i want to export output data in excel file
what is the short code?
this is my script:

```
    echo 'Email Address,';
    for ($i=1;$i<12; $i++){
        echo "email$i,";
    }echo "\n";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['Contact_Email'].',';
        for ($i=1;$i<12; $i++){
            echo (empty($row['email'.$i])?'no':'yes').',';
        }
        echo "\n";
    }

/********************/
Two rows New Update
    echo 'New Email Address,';
    for ($i=1;$i<12; $i++){
        echo "email$i,";
    }echo "\n";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: you have to use an external library to export into excel check this http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/246121/

Comment: i try this but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a coupple of ways you can do this. You could turn your data in [csv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format which you can save to a file and open in excel.

You could connect to Excel via [COM](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.com.php#19688) and create your Excel file that way.

You could use the [DOTNET](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php) class and communicate with Excel using the correct assembly.

You could create your own code to generate the files, but thats a lot of work.
If you want to go this route and avoid having to have Excel installed on the machine that is generating the Excel files I would ask you to look into [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) that does a good job at creating Excel files.

Comment: Thanks for share this but not understand